# How to change every letter typed in an input

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, letter

I've been working on this code for a variable font I designed, where with every letter typed the font-weight gets heavier.

It works alright if I have an output, but is it possible to have the font-weight change directly with every letter typed in the input *testarea* field?

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="myInput" id="testarea" contentEditable="true"> insert text </div>

  <style>
      @import {
      https: //static.wixstatic.com/ufonts/5bda5f_2acfb8a9fc2d407896ec287713383a8d/woff2/file.woff2}
      @font-face {
        font-family:wf_2acfb8a9fc2d407896ec287713383a8d;
        src: url("https://static.wixstatic.com/ufonts/5bda5f_2acfb8a9fc2d407896ec287713383a8d/woff2/file.woff2") format("woff2");
        font-weight: 101 900
      }
      div {
        font-family: 'wf_2acfb8a9fc2d407896ec287713383a8d', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 101;
        font-size: 100px;
      }
  </style>

  <script>
    let initWeight = 100;

    document.getElementById("testarea").onkeypress = function(event) {
      myFunction(event.key)
    };

    function myFunction(letter) {
      innerHTML = '<span style="font-weight:' + initWeight + '">' + letter + '</span>'
      document.getElementById("testarea").innerHTML += innerHTML
      initWeight += 10;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This was my earlier code where the output was changed:

```html
<html>
<style>
    @import {
    https: //static.wixstatic.com/ufonts/5bda5f_04476cfbcbfe4a349a33e0080a539b44/woff2/file.woff2}
    @font-face {
      font-family:wf_04476cfbcbfe4a349a33e0080;
      src: url("https://static.wixstatic.com/ufonts/5bda5f_04476cfbcbfe4a349a33e0080a539b44/woff2/file.woff2") format("woff2");
      font-weight: 101 900
    }
    div {
      font-family: 'wf_04476cfbcbfe4a349a33e0080', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 101;
      font-size: 100px;
    }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="myInput" id="testarea" contentEditable="true"> insert text </div>
  <div id="result" contentEditable="true"></div>


  <script>
    let initWeight = 100;

    document.getElementById("testarea").onkeypress = function(event) {
      myFunction(event.key)
    };

    function myFunction(letter) {
      const letterHTML = '<span style="font-weight:' + initWeight + '">' + letter + '</span>'
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += letterHTML
      initWeight += 10;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you're looking for something like this (?)

**HTML**

```
<h4>Type here</h4>
<div class="myInput" id="testarea" contentEditable="true"></div>
<span></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
const inputDiv = document.getElementById('testarea');
const span = document.querySelector('span');

let weight = 0;

inputDiv.onkeydown = function(e) {
  weight += 100;
  this.style.fontWeight = weight;
  span.textContent = weight;
}
```

The `span` tag is for testing purposes.

Check out this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qhz8brcd/)